# What scriptures describe Draupadi being the reincarnation of Ketaki?

Tags: scripture, mahabharata, draupadi

A story I read in [Tales from the Mahabharata](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=uLFmds7elBAC&pg=PA90&dq=the%20previous%20life%20of%20draupadi&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiGyqqU7afWAhULp48KHewpCMIQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=the%20previous%20life%20of%20draupadi&f=false) speaks of Draupadi being **the previous birth of Daksha Prajapati's daughter Ketaki**.

Ketaki decides to marry Lord Shiva and starts performing penances to please him. Parvati decides to test her devotion and disturbs her in the form of a cow. Ketaki curses it and tries to shoo it away. Parvati then comes to her real form and curses Ketaki to be born as a mortal and wed five men.

The second half of the story goes as described in [Mahabharata](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01200.htm) of Indra and the golden lotuses but my question is about the first half.

**So what scriptures talk of Draupadi being Ketaki, Daksha Prajapati's daughter? And of her penance to Lord Shiva and Parvati's curse?**

Since most of the stories in the book do have some origin in scriptures I'd like to know if this story is true or not.